# Microsoft Compact Keybord is not detected in my Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, microsoft

I have my Microsoft compact keyboard [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/d/microsoft-designer-compact-keyboard/8zhrtr7zcswq?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) which is not detected at all in my ubuntu 22.04. I haven't a dual boot, just an ubuntu.

Does anybody have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: You are sure it is detected and connected in Bluetooth?

Comment: Yep, it connects in bluetooth with my other laptop which is dual boot W10/Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, ControllerMode was bredr in vim /etc/bluetooth/main.conf. I commented the line to put the default value (dual)